# How to communicate between Django, and a Python script running on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, node.js, django, websocket

I have a Django Dashboard sample that I want to use to demonstrate Multi Factor Authentication for an iot hub based on a raspberry pi.

The Pi is connected to a fingerprint sensor, and a temperature/humidity sensor.

A python script is running on the raspberry pi interfacing with the fingerprint and temp/humidity sensors.

I need to communicate between the Django Dashboard, and the python script, so that I can change pages on the web app based on the status of the fingerprint sensor and update a home page showing the values of the temp/humidity sensor.

The dashboard already has implemented user authentication, I will add a fingerprint enrollment step during signup, after which the pi will generate a 6 digit random number to be used as an otp, which will be sent to the user via the email they gave during the signup process. This otp will be entered in the web ui, and sent to the pi for confirmation, after which the pi will send back a otp matched response.

The fingerprints will remain stored on the sensor, the sensor will only return the id of a matched finger, which corresponds with the user id.

During the login process a similar thing will happen, but this time a user will directly place their finger on the sensor, and if a match is found, the web UI will prompt the user to enter a new otp, which will be verified as before.

Now this may seem a little convoluted, but this project needs to maximize security, so generating the otp on the pi is a necessity.

The fingerprint enrollment step can have many conditions for failure, rescanning of the same finger for image training etc, and the web ui must be able to respond to these status changes as soon as possible.

If anyone can help me in this regard, I will be grateful.

I have tried to make an API in Django, but I have been unable to understand the process, some people are also saying that Django may be an unsuitable framework for this as it lacks support for fast DOM updates.

If anyone has suggestions to use some other framework, please share your thoughts.

Reminder: Both the WebUI and python interfacing script will be running locally on the raspberry pi.

Comment: If you want to use Django for most of the stuff you'd need to do here, https://htmx.org/ might be the tool you want.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.